# Maven and Indigo, behind proxy

Tags: eclipse, maven, proxy

I'm having trouble using maven in eclipse. I'm behind a proxy. Maven works fine on CMD as I have configured  on settings.xml. Eclipse's network also is fine with proxy. But m2eclipse won't update my dependencies and comes up with different errors often. This happens with both, embedded Maven or external(defined in *window/preferences/maven/installations*).

For example, I have STS installed and I try to create a SpringTemplate project. It compiles fine except some message on the header of pom.xml, which states:

*Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.7.1 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.7.1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Connect times out*

I tried deleting .lastupdated files in repository but doesn't work.
I tried compiling projects through cmd and then importing in eclipse as maven projects but some similar messages will persist.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the error only for surefire plugin or the error keeps varying from one dependency to another?

Comment: Well I've got three projects and all of them have the same error with surefire plugin!

The funny thing is that today it's the same message + in the end of it _Error code 407, Proxy Authentication Required (The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied)_

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the similar problem before.Here are what I do :

1. Close the project
2. Delete all the folders in the local maven repository
3. Open the project
4. Right click Project--> Maven , and choose "Update Project Configuration" and "Update Dependencies"

Comment: You mean delete some specific folders in local repo?

Comment: I delete everything (i.e all the folders, files and libraries) in the local repo last time , and let the maven rebuild it again .

Comment: But I'll lose all the dependencies of the previous projects! Hmmm

Comment: Yes, you are right . Then you can try to just delete the folder `org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin` .Or you backup your local repo. such that in case of the problem still exist , you can also restore the repo.

Comment: Great help! It works! Friendly speaking, I never though this workaround should work, until I give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It got fixed by removing the proxy settings in settings.xml of Maven. I'm still through proxy though.